# Use of 'My', first or second person

Tags: grammatical-person

I have a quick question. On my website I have a short sentence "Register My Interest".

Is this sentence in first or second person?

I think people jump to first person, but in that case please consider the following two sentences.

> I went to the beach and I took my ball.
>
> You went to the beach and you took my ball.

Thanks,

Stu.

Comment: Please don't use code blocks for prose.

Comment: "You went to the beach and you took me."  Is "me" first person or second person?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense when you put it that way. I would say it is first person but it then differs from the 'Register My Interest' example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a command to the computer providing the web service, instructing it to register (i.e. record) the user's interest. So it's a second-person imperative sentence.

However, it's also possible to interpret it as an incomplete statement about what the user is doing when they use the web site, they're registering their own interest. So it can be viewed as a shortened version of

> I am registering my interest

which is in the first person.

But instructions for the user on a web page are often written in the second person as commands, rather than taking the perspective of the user, e.g.

> Register your interest by filling out the form below

You might want to ask on [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) to find out which form is preferable for your site.

Comment: This is indeed the most reasonable interpretation of 'register my interest', but it *could* also be construed as a second-person imperative directed by the user to the operator of the site, i.e. as the user saying something like 'You, the operator of the site, please register my interest!'

Comment: @jsw29 Very good point. Or anthropomorphizing, "Alexa/Siri, register my interest."

Comment: The way I interpret it is along the lines of 'Computer, Register My Interest' so an instruction to the site to do something. The alternate would be 'Register Your Interest' which would be a valid statement in the same position although also ambiguous. Which could be 'I the computer will register your interest' or 'you can register your interest here'.

Comment: @StuartClarke Yeah, the more I think about it, I think that's more likely, and I've changed the emphasis of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Register My Interest" is first person, English doesn't always differentiate words based on the tense and speaker of a sentence the way some languages do. The word "my" simply means it belongs to the speaker regardless of whether they are talking about their own actions as in the first person "I" example or someone else's as in the "you" example.

Comment: And if it were to read 'Register Your Interest'?

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "Register My Interest" is ambiguous.

**My** is a *possessive* pronoun rather than a *personal* pronoun. Therefore, there is no way of knowing *who* is doing the speaking:

> I / We / You / She / They said, "Register my interest."

Without proper syntactical identification, there is simply no way of determining the POV. As a standalone sentence (without context), it doesn't have a POV.

Comment: Does the fact that it's a personal website not give that context implicitly?

Comment: @Ash Not really. In that context, it's not the site owner saying, "register my," nor is it the visitor saying anything at all. (If they click on it, perhaps.) In fact, "register my" is semantically strange. On a website however, "register your" *could* imply the site owner speaking to the visitor, putting it in first person.

Comment: Okay, I can't say I total agree with your interpretation, except that it is a weird turn of phrase, but I can see where you're coming from.

Comment: @Ash Personally, I would consider buttons or links to be completely neutral. (A red button has no POV.) And buttons can't really be *agents* of dialogue ... Unless, perhaps, they come with sound. Then any sound would be spoken in the third person. ;)

Comment: 'Register Your Interest' was the alternate option. However, according to a marketing firm I'm working with the word 'My' in these kind of statements drastically increases engagement, I've been assured this is based on a study and not just the feeling of an individual and that the difference is significant. I was just wondering why this would be and what the POV is in either case.